# AudioCodes 440HD Boss Admin feature configuration

Tags: voip, lync-2013, skype-for-business-2016

After seeing a demo of how the AudioCodes handle Boss/Admin Delegation I wanted to try deploying this to some users. After some digging I was found the trick was to "flip the SideCar settings". After scouring the phones web interface, and the free phone manager server I didn't see anything regarding the SideCar settings. Looking and the cfg file I found the following line.

```
lync/SideCarUse=SPEED_DIAL_ONLY
```

After not finding any documentation on this setting I wanted to know if anyone here knows what other options are available for this setting. I assume one will be related to the Boss/Admin feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phones need to be on firmware **3.0.4**, or later.
The config should the following settings:

```
lync/SideCarUse=MULTIPLE_BOSS_ADMIN
```